How to run torch dataloader in a sub-process of multiprocessing.Pool?
I want to inference model in multiprocessing, instead of use torch.distributed, how can I use multiprocessing.Pool?
I have to use num_workers=0 in subprocess to avoid error like "daemonic processes are not allowed to have children", but num_workers=0 makes the data reading very very slow. How can I make code below runnable, expecially the num_workers=4?
import multiprocessing
import torch

def process_one_line(line):
    model = load_model()
    dataset = build_dataset()
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, num_workers=4)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lines = get_lines() # 10k lines or more
    with Pool(processes=128) as p:
        for _ in p.imap_unordered(process_one_line, lines):
            pass


You probably shouldn't be loading the dataset and model in all of the 128 child processes..?

Ok there's something odd in this code: you're intent seems to be allocating 128 times (for each worker basically) the same dataloader, dataset and model. In this case it would be better to just define them once in order to save RAM and computational time.
The following code is how I'd work for this task:
model = load_model()
dataset = build_dataset()
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, num_workers=4)

def process_one_batch(batch):
    inputs, targets = batch
    outputs = model(inputs)
    return outputs.detach()

batch_size=1 ensures that you are going to load a sample (what you call line) at each iteration, while num_workers=4 defines number of cores you are going to use to process samples for dataloader. The num_workers=4 setting in my case generate the following warning, but it does not go in conflict with multiprocessing:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:558: UserWarning: This DataLoader will create 4 worker processes in total. Our suggested max number of worker in current system is 2, which is smaller than what this DataLoader is going to create. Please be aware that excessive worker creation might get DataLoader running slow or even freeze, lower the worker number to avoid potential slowness/freeze if necessary.


The process_one_batch function just infer the model's output for the given input, but it is just an example of what you want to do with your samples.
The Pool implementation is the following:
with Pool(processes=128) as p:
        for out in p.imap_unordered(process_one_batch, dataloader):
            print(out)

I've run this code on a google colab notebook and the following dummy function have been used in order to simulate the functions you did not provides:
# Define dummy functions for loading model and dataset
def load_model():
    return torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)

def build_dataset():
    class DummyDataset(Dataset):
        def __len__(self):
            return 1000

        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            return torch.randn((10,))*idx, torch.tensor(idx)
    return DummyDataset()

